# How to connect to a specific Outlook/Exchange account?

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I am making an application to access a particular email account hosted on an Exchange 2003 server and do some stuff to the unread emails found. I do not really know very much about how MAPI works, so I wouldn't be too surprised if I have missed something very obvious! I am (*unfortunately*) using C#, I have read about the issues this may cause (*and am dreading the repercussions, but my boss wants it done like this so..*).

I am struggling to find any good info on how to connect to a specific account!
The application will be run from someones laptop (*let's say mine*), so there will be a default account that Outlook connects to when opened. So:

- Is it possible to connect to another account from a machine where the user already has there own account and probably has Outlook open?
- If it is possible. How do I do this? When initiating the Outlook interop objects the application automatically gets the users account and sets the current user to that.
  I had hoped the `Logon()` method would sort this but no. Even just running
      `Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();`
  Goes and sets the current user to the standard account.

I hope I am making sense (*probably not*), but feel free to ask more detailed questions in the comments and I will reply as quickly as possible. Like I said, I know very little about MAPI and Exchange so I am struggling with how to phrase my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to connect to a specific email account in **Exchange 2003** you need to use [WebDAV](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/articles/9560.aspx), [CDOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142616%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx), or [ExOLEDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms876455%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx). If you were using Exchange 2007+ you could use [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

**Outlook Interop** will only let you connect as the interactive desktop account (*current logged in user*). The only way to connect to other accounts is if the current interactive account has [added the shared mailbox](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-another-person-s-mailbox-to-your-account-HP005242139.aspx).

Comment: (sigh)... I suspected this may be the case but had to go ahead with the other route. Thanks for the advice. Links are useful starting points.

Answer (score 1):

In OOM, you can use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` (assuming the current user has access right to that shared folder).

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) for that - run your code as a domain user who can access the mailboxes in question, call [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonExchangeMailbox` for that user, then open other users' mailboxes using [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetSharedMailbox`/`GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Since Exchange 2013 no longer allows old style RPC connections (only RPC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP), you can use `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` (works for both Exchange 2013 and Exchange 2010).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 accounts defined on one machine, you can use following: [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/2bd6ee48-e38f-4040-b6e6-8600b680404b/c-accessing-my-2nd-mailbox?prof=required)

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

// optional
//object missing = Type.Missing;
//ns.Logon(missing, missing, true, false);

// additional email address 
string recipientName = "myEmail@myDomain";

Outlook.Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
recip.Resolve();

if (recip.Resolved)
{
Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
}
```