# Generating & Sending MS Outlook Tasks

Tags: python, ios, linux, outlook, email-attachments

Is it possible, to create (generate) an e-mail (without any MS COM-objects etc - for example at *nix platform), which will be recognized by MS Outlook as Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *nix platform - the only option you really have is [using EWS to communicate directly with Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563029%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) or have an intermediary service that wraps this EWS behavior up (*Exchange Server 2007+*). If you are using [older versions of Exchange you may have to consider WebDAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562487/175679).

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
    <t:TimeZoneContext>
      <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Eastern Standard Time"/>
    </t:TimeZoneContext>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Items xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
          <Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <Subject>This is a recurring task that was created by using the autogenerated EWS proxies.</Subject>
            <Body BodyType="Text">This task occurs every week.</Body>
            <Recurrence>
              <WeeklyRegeneration>
                <Interval>1</Interval>
              </WeeklyRegeneration>
              <NoEndRecurrence>
                <StartDate>2006-08-15</StartDate>
              </NoEndRecurrence>
            </Recurrence>
            <StartDate>2006-08-15T14:24:51.3876635-07:00</StartDate>
          </Task>
      </Items>
    </CreateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```